# Neural Network giving incorrect answers?

Tags: c++, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

This is a neural network based off of this article: https://stevenmiller888.github.io/mind-how-to-build-a-neural-network/

I tried to follow everything as well as possible, but it doesn't work. Training kind of works, but not very well. Also, any time I enter 0, 0, no matter how I trained it, it responds with 0.
Heres the inputs:
0,0  0
1,0  1
0,1  1
1,1  1

Heres the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

double Sigmoid(double y)
{
    return y / sqrt(1 + pow(y, 2));
}

class Neuron
{
public:
    double output;
    double input1wt;
double input2wt;
double input1;
double input2;

double outputwt;
void Init()
{
    //  srand(time(NULL));
    input1wt = rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.);
    input2wt = rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.);
    outputwt = rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.);
}
double Solve()
{
    if (input1 != -1 && input2 != -1)
    {
        return Sigmoid(input1*input1wt + input2*input2wt);
    }
    else return -1;
}

};

bool Train(Neuron n1, Neuron n2, Neuron n3, double x, double y, double     targetResult, int iterations)
{
double deltaOutputSum;
double deltaHiddenSum[3];
n1.input1 = x;
n1.input2 = y;
n2.input1 = x;
n2.input2 = y;
n3.input1 = x;
n3.input2 = y;
for (int c = 0; c < iterations; c++)
{
    deltaOutputSum = Sigmoid(n1.output * n1.outputwt + n2.output *      n2.outputwt + n3.output * n3.outputwt) * (1 - Sigmoid(n1.output * n1.outputwt + n2.output * n2.outputwt + n3.output * n3.outputwt)) * (targetResult - Sigmoid(n1.output * n1.outputwt + n2.output * n2.outputwt + n3.output * n3.outputwt));


    deltaHiddenSum[0] = deltaOutputSum * n1.outputwt * (Sigmoid(n1.input1 * n1.input1wt + n1.input2 * n1.input2wt) * (1 - Sigmoid(n1.input1 * n1.input1wt + n1.input2 * n1.input2wt)));
    deltaHiddenSum[1] = deltaOutputSum * n2.outputwt * (Sigmoid(n2.input1 * n2.input1wt + n2.input2 * n2.input2wt) * (1 - Sigmoid(n2.input1 * n2.input1wt + n2.input2 * n2.input2wt)));
    deltaHiddenSum[2] = deltaOutputSum * n3.outputwt * (Sigmoid(n3.input1 * n3.input1wt + n3.input2 * n3.input2wt) * (1 - Sigmoid(n3.input1 * n3.input1wt + n3.input2 * n3.input2wt)));

    n1.outputwt += n1.outputwt * deltaOutputSum;
    n2.outputwt += n2.outputwt * deltaOutputSum;
    n3.outputwt += n3.outputwt * deltaOutputSum;

    n1.input1wt += deltaHiddenSum[0];
    n1.input2wt += deltaHiddenSum[1];
    n2.input1wt += deltaHiddenSum[2];
    n2.input2wt += deltaHiddenSum[0];
    n3.input1wt += deltaHiddenSum[1];
    n3.input2wt += deltaHiddenSum[2];

    n1.output = n1.Solve();
    n2.output = n2.Solve();
    n3.output = n3.Solve();
}

return true;
}

int main()
{
srand(time(NULL));
int targetResult = 0;
int a;
int b;
int d;
int c;
Neuron n1 = Neuron();
Neuron n2 = Neuron();
Neuron n3 = Neuron();
n1.Init();
n2.Init();
n3.Init();

for (int c = 0; c < 1000000; c++)
{
    Train(n1, n2, n3, 1, 1, 0, 1);
    Train(n1, n2, n3, 1, 0, 1, 1);
    Train(n1, n2, n3, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    Train(n1, n2, n3, 0, 1, 1, 1);
}
cout << "Done\n";



while (2)
{
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
    //cin >> d;
    n1.input1 = a;
    n1.input2 = b;
    n2.input1 = a;
    n2.input2 = b;
    n3.input1 = a;
    n3.input2 = b;
    //Train(n1, n2, n3, a, b, d, 1000);
    n1.output = n3.Solve();
    n2.output = n3.Solve();
    n3.output = n3.Solve();

    cout << "\n" << Sigmoid(n1.output * n1.outputwt + n2.output * n2.outputwt + n3.output * n3.outputwt) << "\n";
}
return 1;
}
```

Thanks for reading through this if you can, this has really been bothering me.

Comment: Groovy. So the crux of the problem is 0,0 is always 0. Can't see any way it can't be zero. `0*input1wt + 0*input2wt` is going to be 0. `0 / sqrt(1 + pow(0, 2))` also 0.

Comment: In the `Train` function, `Neuron` objects are being passed by value, so you just end up training a temporary copy of each neuron.  You probably want to pass them by reference (`bool Train(Neuron &n1,..`) so that any changes made will stay with the original objects.

Comment: @ChristopherOicles I tried that, but It didnt fix it

Comment: I guess you have two binary inputs and the output is the logical OR? "Training kind of works, but not very well." - what does that mean?

Comment: In any case, you must use references for the code to function.  One other thing I notice here is that in your backprop step, you are updating weights with the entire calculated error.  Usually, weight updates are reduced to a fraction of the error, determined by a learning rate.   Without this, smooth gradient descent does not happen, each epoch updates all weights too coarsely, to some poorly-performing local optimum.

Comment: So I would suggest you select a constant, small learning rate, like 0.1, then wherever you update a weight, multiply the change by this.  Like `n1.input1wt += (deltaHiddenSum[0]) * learning_rate;`

Comment: Also, weights should be able to take on negative values, but your initialization code only produces positive initial weights -- you should fix this.  Also during weight initialization, the magnitudes seem too large to me, ranging between 0 and just under 1.0.  This might be ok, but I would choose smaller magnitudes, like under 0.2 (with negative values, -0.2 to 0.2).  Better yet, forget about the crappy CRT `rand()` API and use the `<random>` library, perhaps using `std::normal_distribution`.